# Why i am getting error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where' " while executing this variable?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The code is given below. I have stored in the variable some value and want to execute it. But it is throwing error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'" . Please help.

```
Declare
@P1_Gold varchar(max), @P1_Gold_Resolution_Met_percentage_final varchar (10),@PreviousMonth varchar(10),@CurrentYear int

SET @PreviousMonth = 'February'
SET @CurrentYear = 2016
SET @P1_Gold_Resolution_Met_percentage_final = '99.9%'
SET @P1_Gold = 'UPDATE BO_SupportKPI_MonthlyTrend_New SET ' + @PreviousMonth  + ' = '
+CONVERT(varchar(10),@P1_Gold_Resolution_Met_percentage_final)+'  where Year=  '
+CONVERT(varchar(6),@CurrentYear)+' and Category = ''Resolution'' and    Support_KPI = ''P1_Gold'''

print @P1_Gold

Execute (@P1_Gold)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `PRINT` statement outputs the followed (line breaks added for clarity):

```
UPDATE BO_SupportKPI_MonthlyTrend_New 
SET February = 99.9%  
where Year=  2016 
and Category = 'Resolution' 
and    Support_KPI = 'P1_Gold'
```

The problem is:

```
SET February = 99.9%
```

This is not valid syntax. The question does not include a definition of the *BO_SupportKPI_MonthlyTrend_New* table, but if the *February* column is a string type, you will need to quote 99.9%, as you did for *Category* and *Support_KPI*.

Please also carefully read:

[SQL Injection – the golden rule](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2015/02/10/sql-injection-the-golden-rule/) by [Rob Farley](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4103/rob-farley)